# Python regex match of port name

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to do a regex match of port name(Ex: eth1/2/3)

```
re.match('[eE][tT][hH](\d+)/(\d+)/(\d)', value)
```

Its catching `eth1/2a/1` as error , but not e`th1/2/1a`.

Can you please help.

Comment: Problem with my regex - not saying the end of string .Thanks Everyone for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happened because in first case `2a` part doesn't match your regular expression. And in second case `th1/2/1` perfectly match `[eE][tT][hH](\d+)/(\d+)/(\d)` and additional a symbol does not matter.

If you need to get something without any additional symbols try to add to your pattern `$` to match end of string.

```
re.match('[eE][tT][hH](\d+)/(\d+)/(\d)$', value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `^[eE][tT][hH]\d+(?:\/\d+){2}$` instead. [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jT7fG9/1)

re.match will search for matches at the start of the input string. Since `eth1/2/1a` matched your pattern at the start (up to the letter a) it would still return a match. To stop that you need to put boundaries at the end of the regex, such as `$` to make sure that you've consumed all the input string before a match is determined.

Comment: With `re.match`, you do not need `^`. Also, `/` does not have to be escaped.